# Please explain the review queue number to me

Tags: support

I'm puzzled by the number displayed in the top bar of the site which purports to show the number of items in the review queue. For me it rarely indicates how many things are actually needing review. For instance, see this screenshot...[image]

So what doe that "10" mean if there is nothing to review?

Comment: Might be cached. I usually see the number there still after I've cleared out my review queue.

Comment: I thought so too. But this has just happened. Queue says "11". I click it, see 1 thing to review. I review it. Number changes to 10. So *some* of it is cached? It's no biggie, I'm just curious as to what is going on there!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, it is number of post which is in 'review' status, not for your personal, but in total. It is "community's review queue" now.

> Previously this notification pertained only to suggested edits, but it
>   now displays the full count of flags of all kinds (except close votes
>   on Stack Overflow) that are eligible for review whenever this number ≥
>   10. This includes flags that I cannot act on personally. I.e., the number reflects the overall community's review queue, not my personal
>   queue, and will continue to display a number even after I have
>   completed the maximum number of reviews for a day, or reviewed all
>   flags that need reviewing. This number is effectively the rest of the
>   community's job to manage after I've reviewed everything I can for the
>   day.